# Citing unofficial translations

Tags: bibliographies

One of the references I use in my text is the famous [Tohoku paper](https://doi.org/10.2748/tmj/1178244839) by Grothendieck:

```
@article{grothendieck57,
author = {Alexander Grothendieck},
title = {{Sur quelques points d'algèbre homologique, I}},
volume = {9},
journal = {Tohoku Mathematical Journal},
number = {2},
publisher = {Tohoku University, Mathematical Institute},
pages = {119 -- 221},
year = {1957},
doi = {10.2748/tmj/1178244839},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.2748/tmj/1178244839}
}
```

However, I actually used the unofficial, unpublished translation by Michael Barr and Marcia Barr - which appears to be taken offline.

**How to reflect the use of the translation in the bibliography?**

Comment: How about adding a note field? Say, `note = {Translated by Marcia L. Barr and Michael Barr as ``Some aspects of homological algebra,'' 2011, available at \url{https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/lubkin/grothendieck-barr_tohoku.pdf}}`.

Comment: Is your question one about the academic practice of _how to cite_ the fact that you used a translation, or about the mechanical practice of _how to incorporate_ a desired piece of text in the bibliographic output? In the former case, you should ask on Academia.StackExchange. In the latter case, please tell us **precisely** what you want included in the bibliography.

Comment: @WillieWong I agree that this should indeed have been asked on Academia SE. Should I delete this question?

Comment: You can just delete it here and re-ask on Academia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `note` field to the entry, say,

```
note    = {Translated unofficially by Marcia~L. Barr and Michael Barr as ``Some
           aspects of homological algebra,'' 2011. Translation available online
           \url{https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/lubkin/grothendieck-barr_tohoku.pdf}},
```

You're of course free to provide whatever information you deem to be useful or helpful. E.g., if it's not sufficiently obvious from the information shown above that you consulted the English translation rather than the French original, you could modify the first sentence in the `note` field to, say, `Version consulted: Unofficial, unpublished English translation by Marcia L. Barr and Michael Barr, ...`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{grothendieck57,
author  = {Alexander Grothendieck},
title   = {Sur quelques points d'algèbre homologique,~{I}},
volume  = {9},
journal = {Tohoku Mathematical Journal},
number  = {2},
publisher = {Tohoku University, Mathematical Institute},
pages   = {119--221},
year    = {1957},
doi     = {10.2748/tmj/1178244839},
URL     = {https://doi.org/10.2748/tmj/1178244839},
note    = {Translated unofficially by Marcia~L. Barr and Michael Barr as ``Some
           aspects of homological algebra,'' 2011. Translation available online
           \url{https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/lubkin/grothendieck-barr_tohoku.pdf}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{xurl,microtype}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```